# Retrofit Observable return data

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, observable, rx-android

Is this correct way to use retrofit together with rx android observable:

In the service:

```
    @GET("/users/{userId}/contacts")
    Observable<Response<List<Contact>>> getContactsForUser(@Path("userId") int userId);
```

In the calling activity:

```
 Subscriber<Response<List<Contact>>>  subscriber = new Subscriber<Response<List<Contact>>>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
        isLoading.set(false);
        hasError.set(true);
        ProblemReporter.Report(throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Response<List< Contact >> listResponse) {
        isLoading.set(false);
        if (listResponse.isSuccessful())
        {
            hasError.set(false);
            List<Contact> list = listResponse.body();
            showList()
        }
        else
        {
            showError();
        }
    }
};
... 
 subscription = peopleService.getContactsForUser(Credentials.getLoggedUser().getId())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(application.subscribeScheduler())
                .subscribe(subscriber);
```

Or should I call it this way:

```
    @GET("/users/{userId}/contacts")
    Observable<List<Contact>> getContactsForUser(@Path("userId") int userId);
```

Without response, i.e. without checking isSuccessful() onComplete assuming that the onComplete would be called if there is no error? 
What is the usual way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct.  Which you use is a matter of preference and your situation. When you call with `Observable<List<Contact>>`, the adapter checks `isSuccessful()` for you, and if it is an error, it wraps the response in an `HttpException`.  Using `Response` gives you more flexibility, but not it is necessary unless you want to do some special handling based on specific response codes.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Correct Method :

```
@GET("/users/{userId}/contacts")
Observable<List<Contact>> getContactsForUser(@Path("userId") int userId);
```

//

```
Subscriber<List<Contact>>  subscriber = new Subscriber<List<Contact>>() {
@Override
public void onCompleted() {

}

@Override
public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
    isLoading.set(false);
    hasError.set(true);
    ProblemReporter.Report(throwable);
}

@Override
public void onNext(List< Contact > listResponse) {
    isLoading.set(false);
    if (listResponse.isSuccessful())
    {
        hasError.set(false);
        List<Contact> list = listResponse.body();
        showList()
    }
    else
    {
        showError();
    }
}
```

};

Comment: sorry, but that code will not compile :( Because the method subscribe will not allow different arguments (List<Contact> vs Response<List<Contact>>)

Comment: Sorry, I have accepted the answer of the iagreen because it provided explanation why would   Observable<List<Contact>> work: 
"the adapter checks isSuccessful() for you, and if it is an error, it wraps the response in an HttpException"  That was what bothered me. 

In the code you have written line: 
 if (listResponse.isSuccessful())
    would not compile. 

But I have upvoted your answer also because I appreciate it.